# 2001 Jeep Cherokee sport check gauges light

Tags: jeep, charging, cherokee

Jeep quit at stop sign and left wife stranded man im in the Dog House.
Question: any thoughts off the cuff for me?

Last week check guages light came on charging gauge dropped all the way negative will jump and run but spits back like its got a fuel problem and then dies.  Installed new battery to get it home gauge showed good charge for about half mile then dropped off again.
 The battery and Alternator have been checked and are testing good. miles are 156k and is maintained on regular basis. When we first got it we were driving on state highway at 60 mph speedo&tach dropped to 0 and air bag light came on but gauges went back up about as fast as they went away, air bag light went back off as well. Not sure this gauge and light issue applies but may, a tech at a chrysler dealer told me there is an issue with cluster harness that may be causing these issues anyone here heard of anything to the point of this comment.

Comment: Usually when I see gauges starting to do weird things and then no charging, etc, with the alt/battery being good, I'll look at two things: 1) connections to battery and alternator; 2) grounds ... *all the grounds* ...

Comment: I agree with Paulster2 grounds are generally the #1 issue with instrument cluster shenanigans. Harness rub though behind the IC, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that your battery is not charging, and you're probably running the battery all the way down, which would explain why it runs ok for a short period of time after you jump it. Have you checked your fuses? there is usually a 'charge fuse' for the voltage regulator. I would look at that first. The next item would be the regulator.

Go over the engine compartment and do a visual check of all the electrical connections, and make sure everything is tight and securely fastened. Vehicle vibration can many times shake loose the wiring and connectors.

It's possible that the odd behavior from the gauges is simply a sign of the low power. I've seen cars where the gauges all drop to 0 as power dies, also the car will mis-fire as it loses power due to a weak or no spark.

Comment: Thank you this advise and will act accordingly if you can think of anything else please dont hesitate to add coments